# How to get color of iframe in php webpage?

Tags: php, jquery, html, iframe, color-picker

I want to create color picker which will select color from other websites onclick in PHP web page.

I have given option to add url for reference website for color selection in my webpage. And I am opening reference url in Iframe but I am not getting color of iframe on clicking of it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          $('iframe').load(function(){   $($("iframe")[0].contentWindow).on('click', function(event) {  alert('test'); });});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="iframe" src="http://www.theuselessweb.com/" width="500px;" height="500px">
        </iframe>
        <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think this is feasible? Where is your mechanism that does the color picking (even on your own page)?

Comment: In same page I am getting color of canvas  

var position = findPos(this);
        var x = e.pageX - position.x;
        var y = e.pageY - position.y;
        var coordinate = "x=" + x + ", y=" + y;
        var canvas = this.getContext('2d');
        var p = canvas.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
        var hex = "#" + ("000000" + rgbToHex(p[0], p[1], p[2])).slice(-6);

Comment: Browsers are no longer allowing javascript to run on other domains (Cross-domain/Cross-origin), So i don't think this is feasible. All sites would have to include you in their Same-origin policy. Some reading on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Comment: I got alternate option to get colors from other website. TO get color first I am getting screenshot of entered url using google pagespeed api and from that image I am getting colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got alternate option to get colors from other website. To get color first I am getting screenshot of entered url using google pagespeed api and from that image I am getting colors codes